# 3D PDF cycling between views animation

Tags: pdf, 3d, media9, javascript, movie15

I'm creating a 3D pdf with latex and movie15 and I added some views for my u3d object...
Then I added `turntable.js` to manually change a view of the object...
till now everything is fine

It is possible to add a jscript to automatically cycle all the views i.e. changing the view each second?

The best would be to associate the start stop to the standard animation toolbar button

here is the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[3D]{movie15}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\includemovie[
poster,
toolbar,
label=dice,
text=(dice.u3d),
3Droo=27,
3Dlights=Cube,
3Djscript=turntable.js,
3Dviews2=dice.vws
]{.5\linewidth}{.5\linewidth}{dice.u3d}\\
\movieref[3Dviewindex=N]{dice}{Click here} ...\\
\movieref[3Dcalculate=60]{dice}{This link} ...
\end{document}
```

1. [dice.u3d](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/movie15/doc/files/dice.u3d)
2. [dice.vws](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/movie15/doc/files/dice.vws)
3. [turntable.js](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/movie15/doc/javascript/turntable.js)

Comment: Please provide the code, so that we can play with the code. So its impossible to help you (from my side)....

Comment: the code is just "turntable.js" from movie15 package http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/movie15/doc/javascript/turntable.js

Comment: A minimal working example is required. I suggest also to remove movie15 and replace to media9 package. The community for sure need a so called Minimal working example. Show, how you have tried so solve your problem and provide code, so that we can copy and past. So we ware able to play with the code...

Comment: @PeterEbelsberger the code is just "turntable.js" from movie15 package http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/movie15/doc/javascript/turntable.js and the code is the "dice" example in movie15.pdf `\includemovie[
poster,
toolbar,
label=dice,
text=(dice.u3d),
3Droo=27,
3Dlights=Cube,
3Djscript=turntable.js,
3Dviews2=dice.vws
]{
.5\linewidth
}{
.5\linewidth
}{dice.u3d}
\movieref[
3Dviewindex=N
]{dice}{Click here}` (_I would prefer to stay on movie15 for some compatibility issues on pdf viewers_)  I just would need to animate automatically the dice among the views...

Comment: Sorry, please read this http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe currently I am not able to help you unless you provide code which is compileable like "pdflatex mwe.tex"  this is too less information for me. Maybe other users can help you.

Comment: @PeterEbelsberger sorry, the minimal working example, as I told you, is in movie15.pdf and in movie15 package where you can find also dice.u3d to build and compile everything as you are requiring... [dice.u3d](ftp://ftp.tug.org/tex/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/movie15/files/dice.u3d) I don't know what I could give more...

Comment: There is no MWE inside the documentation. I have to build a new documentstructure and paste the code inside. I won't do that for you. Did you read the link above? I am out. Sorry.

Comment: citing "> I have to build a new documentstructure and paste the code inside. I won't do that for you." @PeterEbelsberger just for completeness I added the missing part of the code I didn't wrote before (it is just few includes at the beginning)   Citing you "I won't do that for you." I haven't asked you anything... if you are not willing/can help just don't partecipate in the forum... cheers

Comment: Thanks for the MWE. I was willing to help. but search the web to finde the code is not funny. If you expect help, you should make it easy to help you. My first approach to help you with this MWE failed. The second image gives me a javascript error. Don't know at the moment why this occure. Can you give once more the motivation not to change to media9? (currently I do not know if this solve the problem. You told us, that here are compaitbility reasons? Which ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `media9` package should be used instead of the obsolete `movie15`, as in the example below.

Here is a JavaScript that cycles through the predefined views. The view changes every 5 seconds. As requested, the toolbar Play/Pause button can be used to pause/resume the animation. For further info about 3D JavaScript, see [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/Acro12_MasterBook/JS_3D_Intro/JS_3D_Intro.htm).

```
var time=0; 
var curViewIdx=0;

timeEvHnd=new TimeEventHandler();
timeEvHnd.onEvent=function(event) {
  time += event.deltaTime;
  if (time>=5) {
    time = 0;
    curViewIdx++;
    if(curViewIdx == runtime.viewCount) curViewIdx=0;
    runtime.setView(curViewIdx, true);
  }
}

runtime.addEventHandler(timeEvHnd);
// runtime.pause();
```

The complete example (except [dice.u3d](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/movie15/doc/files/dice.u3d))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{mwe} %example image file used as poster for 3D content
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{filecontents}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{filecontents*}{changeView.js}
var time=0; 
var curViewIdx=0;

timeEvHnd=new TimeEventHandler();
timeEvHnd.onEvent=function(event) {
  time += event.deltaTime;
  if (time>=5) {
    time = 0;
    curViewIdx++;
    if(curViewIdx == runtime.viewCount) curViewIdx=0;
    runtime.setView(curViewIdx, true);
  }
}

runtime.addEventHandler(timeEvHnd);
// runtime.pause();
\end{filecontents*}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{filecontents*}{dice.vws}
VIEW=Front
  ROO=27
END
VIEW=Back
  ROO=27
  C2C=0 1 0
END
VIEW=Left
  ROO=27
  C2C=-1 0 0
END
VIEW=Right
  ROO=27
  C2C=1 0 0
END
VIEW=Top
  ROO=27
  C2C=0 0 1
END
VIEW=Bottom
  ROO=27
  C2C=0 0 -1
END
VIEW=Fish Eye at Centre
  AAC=130
END
\end{filecontents*}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\includemedia[
  width=0.5\linewidth,height=0.5\linewidth,
  activate=pageopen,
  3Dtoolbar, 3Dmenu,
  3Dviews=dice.vws,
  add3Djscript=3Dspin­tool.js, % turntable rotation of 3D object
  add3Djscript=changeView.js
]{\includegraphics{example-image}}{dice.u3d}

\end{document}
```

Comment: **Thanks a lot Alex!** Great package :) **PS** _I'm using movie15 because with movie9 I have an issue with FoxitReader in windows_ ... if I use a background for the animation to be displayed if a different pdf viewer from Acrobat is used, I just don't see the background image  if I use movie9(tested with Foxir Reader 7.3)... thanks again Maurice

Comment: sorry I wrote movie9 but I meant media9 ... if you need more details I can send them to you .... thanx

Comment: @user3084508 Ok, will have a look into the Foxit issue as soon as p.

Comment: @user3084508 The poster image/text is inserted in the first mandatory argument. Here it is empty and you won't see anything in alternative readers or in AR with disabled 3D content. Just use `\includegraphics{...}` in the poster argument to provide a poster image.

Comment: Hi @AlexG I can confirm that I cannot see the background image using media9 not using \includegraphics nor using wallpaper package in Foxit Reader windows 8... `\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\addtolength{\wpXoffset}{-0.8cm}
\addtolength{\wpYoffset}{2cm}

\begin{document}
 \includemedia[
 ....
 ....
 ]{\includegraphics{dice-bg.png}}{dice.u3d}
 \ThisCenterWallPaper{1.0}{frame.png} 
\end{document}` the area where the 3d object is on, will not displayed correctly (the strange is that I can see it on the Thumbnails) ...

Comment: @user3084508 I edited the example to show a poster image if 3D is not activated/ PDF opened in alternative PDF reader (Foxit, Ghostview, ...). In Foxit I see the embedded example image.

Comment: humm ... the same example for me is not showing the background image in foxit reader... I'm going to check it later at home if I can make it workable as it should ... keep in touch, thanks

Comment: I have the same behavior at home... Foxit reader 7.1.3 and 7.3 ... I cannot obtain a pdf with the background displayed correctly  (with sumatra the background is fine)... I don't know what could I send you to give more info to replicate that... MiKTeX 2.9 and TeXStudio 2.9.4; media9 0.5.1 ... thank you again

Comment: @user3084508 : You may send me the stuff by e-mail, if you don't mind.

Comment: I was going to post the examples @AlexG, but I discovered a bit more... opening the media9 pdf in Foxit I get this warning:
_This document contains interactive form fields._ and the background image is not correctly displayed
with movie15pdf I get this message: _the PDF document contains 3D data._ ... and the background image is correctly displayed; I just noticed that if I comment `activate=pageopen,` in media9, the background image is displayed until I click on it "Click to activate" ... I hope that may help... otherwise I will send you the samples and generated pdfs by mail :)

Comment: @user3084508 Maybe by mail, so that I can compile your  example at once. (No need to re-create it myself which saves a lot of time.)

Comment: Hi @AlexG, I've just sent you the examples :)  please let me know if you get or not them and update me :)

Comment: @user3084508 Ok, arrived.