# Change Javascript cycle velocity

Tags: pdf, 3d, media9, javascript

I'm creating a 3D pdf with latex and media9 and I added some views for my .u3d object.
Now i Have found a script which changes the views automatically:[Link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/308041/192028)

It is possible to change these script to rotate more fluent between the views?

It would be also nice to change the velocity.
I have changed the time between the views, but now it rotates very fast.
But it still stops briefly at a previously defined view point.
If i lower the time even further, it skips views.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{tikz} % for creating a poster
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{filecontents}

%filecontents in the lower comment

\begin{document}
 \includemedia[
%   draft,
  width=\linewidth  ,height=\linewidth,
  activate=pageopen,
  3Dtoolbar, 3Dmenu,
  3Dviews=views.vws,
  add3Djscript=3Dspintool.js, % turntable rotation of 3D object
  add3Djscript=viewchange.js
]{\includegraphics{example-image}}{dice.u3d}
\end{document}
```

Additional Files: [dice.u3d](https://ftp.agdsn.de/pub/mirrors/latex/dante/macros/latex/contrib/media9/doc/files/dice.u3d)

```
%.js file muss manuell erstellt werden (ohne inhalt)
%\begin{filecontents*}{changeView.js} 
%var time=0; 
%var curViewIdx=0;
%
%timeEvHnd=new TimeEventHandler();
%timeEvHnd.onEvent=function(event) {
%  time += event.deltaTime;
%  if (time>=5) {
%    time = 0;
%    curViewIdx++;
%    if(curViewIdx == runtime.viewCount) curViewIdx=0;
%    runtime.setView(curViewIdx, true);
%  }
%}
%
%runtime.addEventHandler(timeEvHnd);
%// runtime.pause();
%\end{filecontents*}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\begin{filecontents*}{3Dspintool.js} 
%runtime.setCurrentTool(runtime.TOOL_NAME_SPIN);
%\end{filecontents*}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\begin{filecontents*}{views.vws}
%VIEW=1
%  COO=3.8412740230560303 0.7929028272628784 -1.2368221282958984
%  C2C=0.6128408908843994 -0.5093194842338562 0.6041686534881592
%  ROO=22.314074206985236
%  LIGHTS=Headlamp
%END
%VIEW=2
%  COO=3.8412740230560303 0.7929028272628784 -1.2368221282958984
%  C2C=0.62525874376297 -0.015961874276399612 0.7802542448043823
%  ROO=22.31407283934709
%  LIGHTS=Headlamp
%END
%VIEW=3
%  COO=3.8412740230560303 0.7929028272628784 -1.2368221282958984
%  C2C=0.5805690288543701 0.5310713052749634 0.6171732544898987
%  ROO=24.54547258883754
%  LIGHTS=Headlamp
%END
%VIEW=4
%  COO=3.8412740230560303 0.7929028272628784 -1.2368221282958984
%  C2C=0.39592796564102173 0.8039077520370483 0.4438166618347168
%  ROO=27.00001243308452
%  LIGHTS=Headlamp
%END
%VIEW=5
%  COO=3.8412740230560303 0.7929028272628784 -1.2368221282958984
%  C2C=-0.8026273846626282 0.48044249415397644 0.3535027801990509
%  ROO=26.999997739438562
%  LIGHTS=Headlamp
%END
%VIEW=6
%  COO=3.8412740230560303 0.7929028272628784 -1.2368221282958984
%  C2C=-0.706401526927948 -0.5793313980102539 0.4066595733165741
%  ROO=26.999995478876937
%  LIGHTS=Headlamp
%END
%VIEW=7
%  COO=3.8412740230560303 0.7929028272628784 -1.2368221282958984
%  C2C=0.3001320958137512 -0.738174319267273 0.6041684150695801
%  ROO=27.00000226056125
%  LIGHTS=Headlamp
%END
%\end{filecontents*}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: The speed of the animated view change is hardwired in Acrobat Reader, there is no way to change it, apart from disabling it completely:  `runtime.setView(curViewIdx, false);`. It is the second argument that determines whether the view change is to be animated ("`true`") or not ("`false`").

Comment: See: https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/acrobatsdk/html2015/index.html#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FJS_3D_API%2FsetView1.htm